# Weird "Something is wrong - perhaps a missing item"

Tags: errors

currently, LaTeX drives me wild on a very weird

> "Something is wrong - perhaps a missing item"

It happens in line 3 of the following document, although it only imports the `scrpage2-package`. Commenting the line doesn't even fix it - the same error appears. Any clues what could be the reason of this weird error?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\title{Szene 12 \\ TenSing Theaterskript}
\author{Lukas Rose}
\date{2016}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\casttitlename}{Personen}
\renewcommand{\actname}{Akt}
\renewcommand{\scenename}{Szene}
\renewcommand{\casttitlefont}{\scshape \bf \LARGE}
\renewcommand{\scenenamefont}{\scshape \LARGE}
\renewcommand{\printscenenum}{\scenenumfont \thescene}
\renewcommand{\printscenetitle}[1]{\scenetitlefont \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Banane} #1}

\begin{CharacterGroup}{Omas}
\GCharacter{Eine/r Alte/r}{Eine/r Alte/r}{hb}
\end{CharacterGroup}

\newcommand{\ac}[1]{\item\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\hb,colframe=Red]#1\end{tcolorbox}}

\DramPer

\setcounter{scene}{11}
\scene{}
\StageDir{}

\begin{drama}
\ac {\direct{Banane} Hallo! Ich kann sprechen!}
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remove `\scene` it works...

Comment: Your dramatist package is creating a toc entry for chapter. This won't work with an article class, but you can use \documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}

Comment: Works for me. Should have seen this earlier :D

Comment: But I've always been using the dramatist package with KOMA Script article class... How can this be?

Comment: In my case, which comes from copypasting the body of a paper in another one with a different preamble, the error was caused by a missing `\usepackage{enumitem}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using chapter level constructs in the table of contents but the article class does not have chapters, use report:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage{scrpage2} %Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\begin{document}
\title{Szene 12 \\ TenSing Theaterskript}
\author{Lukas Rose}
\date{2016}
\maketitle


\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\casttitlename}{Personen}
\renewcommand{\actname}{Akt}
\renewcommand{\scenename}{Szene}
s\renewcommand{\casttitlefont}{\scshape \bfseries \LARGE}
\renewcommand{\scenenamefont}{\scshape \LARGE}
\renewcommand{\printscenenum}{\scenenumfont \thescene}
\renewcommand{\printscenetitle}[1]{\scenetitlefont \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Banane} #1}

\begin{CharacterGroup}{Omas}
\GCharacter{Eine/r Alte/r}{Eine/r Alte/r}{hb}
\end{CharacterGroup}

\newcommand{\ac}[1]{\item\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\hb,colframe=Red]#1\end{tcolorbox}}

\DramPer

\setcounter{scene}{11}
\scene{}
\StageDir{}

\begin{drama}
\ac {\direct{Banane} Hallo! Ich kann sprechen!}
\end{drama}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your document records a `chapter` entry in the `.toc` file, and this confuses the document class `scrartcl`. The document compiles without error if using class `scrbook`.